# Item selection in spinner doesn't detect in MyOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have activity with 3 spinners and selection of 1st spinner is related to 2nd and 2nd selection is related to the 3rd, so I have the spinner code one inside one.
`CrustSp, SizeSp and extraDescriptionOneSP` are the 3 spinners I have. I have loaded the items to the Spinners and I can select a value as well. But my problem is whenever i made a selection in CrustSp and SizeSp doesn't show in `MyOnItemSelectedListener().` But if I made a selection in `extraDescriptionOneSP`  it shows inside `MyOnItemSelectedListener()`.

I can't figure where I have gone wrong, anyone can point out where I have gone wrong it will be really helpful.

This the code

```
            crust = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(crust);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, crust);
            dataAdapterCru
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            crustSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterCru);

            crustSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                    ActivityPizzaCustomize.this) {

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {

                    String crustSelectedItem = crustSP.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString();

                    List<String> resultSizes = getFilteredSizes(crustSelectedItem);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            resultSizes);
                    dataAdapterDes
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);

                    sizeSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this) {

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            String sizeSelectedItem = sizeSP
                                    .getSelectedItem().toString();

                            List<String> resultTopping = getFilteredToppings(sizeSelectedItem);

                            extraDescriptionOneSP
                                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this));
                            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    ActivityPizzaCustomize.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    resultTopping);
                            dataAdapterExtraDesOne
                                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            extraDescriptionOneSP
                                    .setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesOne);
                            extraDescriptionOneSP
                                    .setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                            dataAdapterExtraDesOne,
                                            R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this));

                        }

                    });

                }
            });
```

`MyOnItemSelectedListener`  method,

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
    Activity activity;
    String StrOneSPPosition;

    public MyOnItemSelectedListener(Activity p_activity) {
        activity = p_activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        // check which spinner triggered the listener
        switch (parent.getId()) {

        case R.id.sp_crust: {

            String StrCrustSPPosition = String.valueOf(crustSP
                    .getSelectedItemPosition());
            System.out.println("crust = " + StrCrustSPPosition);
            System.out.println("crust = " + position);
            CrustSPPosition = Integer.parseInt(StrCrustSPPosition);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using the selected position to determine the data for next spinner. BTW you should not make new adapter for each selection, instead reuse the once made adapter.

Comment: List<String> resultSizes = getFilteredSizes(crustSelectedItem); that line does the filtering and returns the required stuff. I have the issue with why MyOnItemSelectedListener doesn't detect the selection of CrustSp and SizeSp

Comment: I was mentioning that "position" obtained in the method onItemSelected. How are you determining which data to use without using that "position" value?

Comment: check my updated question, this code works with 3rd spinner but not with 1st and 2nd spinner

Comment: I don't know why are you making things so complex. I think the problem is that you are overriding the onItemSelectedListener without calling the super method.

Comment: THis is my 1st android project, so struggling alot. you mind helping me to do this properly?

Comment: either move all the cases within the MyOnItemSelectedListener and dont override methods, just set onselectedlistener. or make seperate classes for each spinner.